# Cannot stop the debug

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013

Hi I am using the Microsoft Visual Studio. I started the debugging process by hitting F5. I would want to stop the debug without stopping the application(Visual Studio). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Shift+F5 or Stop Debugging will terminate the process.

Instead you want the **Detach All** command from the **Debug** menu.

Answer (score -1):

shift + F5 in keyboard shortcut or click stop debugging button at the top right corner of the visual studio